# References for learning to write multi-threaded application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

One of library I am working on, requires support of asynchronous operations. This library communicates with external devices using serial port (RS232) which can be quiet slow.

I went through many MSDN articles but I am not feeling confident. I think if you are 100% sure that your multi-threaded application is thread-safe, then it might actually work but if you think it might work, it will surely **NOT** work.

Please can you suggest any articles/books to learn multi-threading in .net/C#? Something that tells me the right way to implement that in a .NET library (using right patterns etc).

I would prefer a book since a book normally covers a topic thoroughly (whereas articles normally hit a particular topic at once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) that's quite good for understanding the base of threading, and that explains the difference between almost all synchronization/threading objects available in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Hmm...A good one. Pretty thorough and qualifies to be called a book. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Managed Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd.aspx) and [Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) was my first step to learning. One of the more advanced steps is [Joe Duffy's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X). I'm not sure what goes inbetween, for me it was mis-understanding, disaster and woe, I hope your travels are safer. :)

Answer (score 1):

$17.50 for a  good [ebook on .NET Multithreading](http://www.manning.com/dennis/).

[Chapter 1](http://www.manning-source.com/books/dennis/dennis_ch01.pdf) and [Chapter 9](http://www.manning-source.com/books/dennis/dennis_ch09.pdf) available on the site, to get a taster.